# Why isn't my insertion sort working?

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to implement an insertion sort from reading the vague description, so I may very well be going about it the wrong way. However, from what I can see this should work:

```
import random

arr = []
c_num = 0

for i in range(0, 10):
    arr.append(random.randint(0, 10))

def InsertionSort(unsorted_array, current_num):
    smallest_num = unsorted_array[current_num]
    smallest_num_index = 0
    isSorted = True

    for i in range(current_num, len(unsorted_array) - 1):
        if unsorted_array[i] < smallest_num:
            smallest_num = unsorted_array[i]
            smallest_num_index = i
            isSorted = False

    if isSorted:
        return unsorted_array
    else:
        temp = unsorted_array[current_num]
        unsorted_array[current_num] = smallest_num
        unsorted_array[smallest_num_index] = temp
        current_num += 1
        return InsertionSort(unsorted_array, current_num)

print(InsertionSort(arr, c_num))
```

It will sort the first few elements, and then just print out the now slightly-sorted array, but I can't see what I am missing to get the whole thing sorted.

Sample:

input = [9, 8, 5, 4, 5, 8, 2, 10, 7, 5]

output = [2, 4, 5, 8, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5]

Comment: You are looking for where to move the current value in the *unsorted* part of the list (at the right of it), while you should look for where to move it in the *sorted* part of the list (at the left of it).

Comment: Can you show us the data set you tried and the result you had?

Comment: @LioraHaydont Please see updated question.

Comment: Why don't you look at the correct insertion sort algorithm, for example on Wikipedia?

Comment: @trincot Because I am hoping to be told what I am doing wrong so I can correct it myself and avoid making the same mistake again. I am not too sure I understand what you mean in your last message though.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong: insertion sort involves several assignments (shifts) at the left of a given index, to find the spot where to insert the value at that index. After inserting it there, only then it goes on to the next index. Your code only performs one swap per recursion level. If that would work you would have implemented a way to sort any array with at the most n swaps. That is not insertion sort.